# how to use Union In sql sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
select user_id,name, login,lastseen from users where user_id 
in((select friend_id from connections where user_id=1 and connection=1) 
union (select user_id from connections where friend_id=1 and connection=1))
```

I wana to do some work like this but this query is showing error. If I run this sub query independently without backets it is working fine.
and also how can I rewrite this query to increase the perforamance

Comment: Please Tag what specifically DB are you using.

Answer (score 2):

Skip the `IN` with a `UNION`, do an `EXISTS` instead:

```
select user_id, name, login, lastseen
from users u
where exists (select 1 from connections c
              where c.connection = 1
                and ((u.user_id = c.friend_id and c.user_id = 1) or
                     (c.user_id = u.user_id and c.friend_id = 1)))
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would be better (I presume faster but can't see why)?
I feel its less readable so would like to understand why its better.

Comment: @Kamil, I suppose it will only read connections table once, instead of twice in the union case. (Since we don't know the dbms I can't tell for sure.)

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra brackets

```
select user_id,name, login,lastseen 
from users 
where user_id 
in (
    select friend_id 
    from connections 
    where user_id=1 and connection=1

    union 

    select user_id 
    from connections 
    where friend_id=1 and connection=1
   )
```